# For Authorization Code with PKCE. In Salesforce Which OAuth Flows Support this?

Tags: api, connected-apps, oauth

I have a requirement to implement an oAuth 2.0 Auth Service with PKCE when accessing Salesforce.  I was looking to find out which Salesforce OAuth2.0 Flows support this.

I wondered if PKCE is only available for the Web Server oAuth Auth Flow or if it's available for other Flows also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oAuth specification perspective: PKCE (RFC 7636) is an extension to the Authorization Code flow. No other grant types (aka flows) have this "feature". In Salesforce universe, Authorization Code grant is known as the Web Server flow.

Comment: Thank you for you help